# Improve time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I have created this algorithm which all it does is finds the pairs of integers  that have the same product and the integers in the pairs have to be different. The product must not exceed the 1024. This is the easiest way I could come up to doing it, is there a way I could improve the efficiency and time complexity of this algorithm?

Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pairs {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        int nums[] = new int[1024];
        for(int i = 1;i<=1024;i++){
            nums[i-1] = i;
        }
        findPairs(nums);

    }

    static void findPairs(int [] nums){


        ArrayList<IntPair> pairs = new ArrayList<IntPair>();
        ArrayList<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();

        IntPair tempObject;
        Products tempProduct;
        int tempMultiplication = 0;

        for(int i =0;i<nums.length;i++){

            for(int j=0;j<nums.length;j++){

                tempObject = new IntPair(nums[i],nums[j]);
                pairs.add(tempObject);

                }


            }

        for(IntPair p:pairs){
            tempProduct = new Products(p.x,p.y);

            if(tempProduct.product <= 1024){
                products.add(tempProduct);
            }


        }


        for(int i = 0;i<products.size();i++){

            tempMultiplication = products.get(i).product;

            for(int j = 0;j<products.size();j++){

                 if(products.get(j).product == tempMultiplication)
                 {
                    if(products.get(i).x == products.get(j).x || products.get(i).y == products.get(j).y) {


                     }
                    else if (products.get(i).x == products.get(j).y || products.get(j).x == products.get(j).y || products.get(i).x == products.get(i).y){


                    }
                     else{
                         System.out.println("Matching pair found:("+ products.get(i).x + ","+products.get(i).y+")"  + "("+ products.get(j).x + ","+products.get(j).y+")" );
                     }


                 }


            }

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: Pair up all of the (distinct) integers, put them into a `Map<Integer, List<Pair>>`, where the key is the product, and the value is the list of pairs with that product.

Comment: There's a lot to improve here. Using set/map will make you avoid lot of iterations (Also note that j=0 should be j=i+1)

Comment: You can't improve the worst case time complexity: if you're looking for pairs of things, it's got to be at least `O(n^2)`. All you can do is to reduce the multiplicative constant.

Comment: So basically this algorithm I created isn't that bad right?

Comment: @Jack Could  you explain why I need to use j = i+1 rather than j = 0 please? thanks for your answer

Comment: You don't need to pair `nums[i]` with `nums[j]` if `j <= i`.

Comment: "isn't that bad" Hard to say, it's hard to read. It looks pretty verbose, and doesn't actually implement your criteria, and you've not said anything about your input size. But remember that two algorithms can both have `O(n^2)` time complexity, but one can be much faster than the other; and an algorithm with worse time complexity can be better than one with better time complexity, depending upon input size (e.g. bubble sort can be better than merge sort on small arrays).

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy, you were of much help

Comment: What's n? If 1024 is a fixed constant, and n is the size of the input, then it's O(n) to filter the input array to remove elements not in the range -1024 to 1024, and remove duplicates, and then O(1) to iterate over the at most ~500k pairs. If n is the maximum product (here 1024), then the smaller value in any product can be at most sqrt(n), and O(n^(3/2)) is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't improve the time *complexity* of your algorithm. It is `O(n^2)`, which is as good as you can do if you are comparing all pairs in the input.

But that's not to say that you can't improve the *running time*. Not all `O(n^2)` algorithms are equally good; you can make it run faster by getting it to do less work; in this case, that basically means skipping checking of numbers whose product can't be equal.

Put the pairs into buckets which have equal product:

```
Map<Integer, List<int[]>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length; ++j) {
    if (nums[i] == nums[j] || nums[i]*nums[j] > 1024) continue;

    map.computeIfAbsent(nums[i]*nums[j], ArrayList::new)
        .add(new int[] {nums[i], nums[j]});
  }
}
```

Then just iterate all of the pairs of pairs within each bucket:

```
for (List<int[]> list : map.values()) {
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); ++j) {
      System.out.printf(
          "Matching pair found: %s %s%n",
          Arrays.toString(list.get(i)),
          Arrays.toString(list.get(j)));
    }
  }
}
```

This is still `O(n^2)` in the worst case, which is where all pairs of numbers have an equal product, meaning that the iteration over pairs with equal product is just iterating all pairs. I doubt that's actually possible, though, without all numbers being equal, which is prohibited by the check that the numbers in the pair are distinct.

You may be able to shave off a bit of time by sorting `nums` first, and then breaking the top inner loop once `nums[i]*nums[j] > 1024` rather than continuing; it depends on how big `nums` is as to whether it is worth sorting it (having potentially copied it, if you don't want to change the input array).

Comment: I have a similar question on algorithm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556775/populate-string-value-in-a-map-only-if-matches-the-threshold-bytes). Trying to make fixed size string before putting it into map. I am not sure I got it right so wanted to check with you.